# how add TListBoxGroupHeader with code

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a fmx form with a TListBox on it (C++ Rad Studio).  At design time i can right-click on the ListBox and in the Items Editor I can add a GroupHeader.  Is it possible to do that in code or is it only an option at design time?

thanks,
russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your TListBox is called "MyListBox", this is how you would add it to the end of the list in Delphi:

```
var
  lListHeader: TListBoxGroupHeader;
begin
  lListHeader := TListBoxGroupHeader.Create(MyListBox);
  lListHeader.Parent := MyListBox;
end;
```

Comment: Doing this in C++ is described here:  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_(iOS_and_Android)